# How to solve Auth guard [web] is not defined problem

Tags: laravel, authentication

I make 2 guards 1. For admin and 2. for student. Now when i click on my button to show the login form i always caught that error that Auth guard [web] is not defined.Now how i solve this.
here is my config/auth.php

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
 'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'student',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Student::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

I am trying login the admin using admin guard.Please help me to solve that and i dont use default User.php model.

[image: Full error message]

Comment: Please post the full error message, there are a few places that the default web guard is called

Comment: picture is not added, i tried two times, can you check from here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2nka.png

Comment: at the very top you have the default guard set to web but you removed that guard. You can try changing the default to either student or admins

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you're removing `web` guard from the application.

Just change your default guard from `web` to your new guard.

```php
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'admins',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: @TanvirAhmed make sure you run php artisan config:clear after you make any changes to the config file

Comment: yes problem is fixed thanks but can you little explain me or give a hint that i dont have the user model but why i have to import here

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Sorry, I missed something. Just check updated answer.

Comment: but i dont want be to use this guard as default but if the later i got stucked i will let you know

Comment: So, what do you want? You only have `admins`, `students`. and `api`. Just pick one of them.